# The loaderless bootloader

Tags: assembly

I began this month with trying to discover how shellcode is made. My search led me to wanting to learn assembly, so I wrote a simple bootloader with NASM:

```
                bits       16               ; 16 bit real mode
                org        0x7C00           ; loader start in memory

start:          jmp        main             ; goto main

bgetkey:        mov        ax, 0            ; clear register a
                mov        ah, 0x10         ; 
                int        16h              ; interrupt bios keyboard
                ret                         ; return
                .buf       dw 0             ; buffer size one word

prints:         pusha                       ; 
.loop:          mov        ah, 0x0e         ; 
                mov        al, [si]         ; 
                cmp        al, 0            ; check for null terminator
                jz         print_end        ; stop printing
                mov        bh, 0x00         ; 
                mov        bl, 0x07         ; 
                int        0x10             ; interrupt bios tty
                inc        si               ; next character
                jmp        .loop            ; jump beginning
print_end:      popa                        ; 
                ret                         ; return

main:           mov        ax, 0x0000       ; clear register a
                mov        ds, ax           ; 
                mov        si, welcome      ; copy welcome string pointer
                call       prints           ; print string
newinput:       mov        bx, mem          ; set register b to memory start
                add        bx, word 2       ; increment by size of memory ptr
                mov        word [mem], bx   ; set pointer at first memory byte
type:           mov        si, qbuf         ; set byte buffer ptr for printing
                call       bgetkey          ; capture keyboard input
                mov        [qbuf], al       ; copy key byte to buffer
                call       prints           ; print the character
                mov        bx, [mem]        ; copy memory stop to b, decrement
                cmp        bx, stop - 1     ; check for overflow preserve null
                je         oom              ; halt - no more memory
                mov        byte [bx], al    ; copy keystroke to memory
                add        bx, byte 1       ; increment memory pointer
                mov        [mem], bx        ; restore memory pointer to memory
                cmp        byte [qbuf], 0x0D; check for carriage return
                jne        type             ; goto next key if not found
                mov        si, newline      ; copy pointer to line feed string
                call       prints           ; print the line feed

                mov        bx, mem + 2      ; restore start of valid memory
readmem:        cmp        byte [bx], 0x0D  ; check for carriage return
                je         readmemdone      ; if found begin another input line
                mov        cl, [bx]         ; register character byte
                mov        byte [qbuf], cl  ; copy byte to string buffer
                mov        si, qbuf         ; copy buffer ptr for printing
                call       prints           ; print the character
                inc        bx               ; increment memory pointer
                jmp        readmem          ; read another character byte
readmemdone:    mov        byte [qbuf], 0x0D; copy carriage return to buffer
                call       prints           ; print carriage return
                mov        si, newline      ; copy line feed string to buffer
                call       prints           ; print line feed
                jmp        newinput         ; ready new line

oom:            mov        si, outomem      ; copy out of memory message ptr
                call       prints           ; print message

halt:           mov        si, halting      ; copy halting mesage ptr
                call       prints           ; print final message
                hlt                         ; halt the cpu

                welcome db "boot", 0x0A, 0x0D, 0x00
                newline db 0x0A, 0x00
                outomem db 0x0A, 0x0D, "out of memory", 0x0A, 0x0D, 0x00
                halting db 0x0A, 0x0D, "halting", 0x00
                qbuf       dw 0, 0
                mem        db 0

times 0200h - 2 - ($ - $$)db 0
                stop       dw 0xAA55
```

I use a script to compile and run the loader. It makes a fallback copy of all my files each time:

```
nasm -o boot.bin -f bin boot.asm && \
tar -zcvf ~/os-$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S).tar.gz ../os && \
qemu boot.bin
```

If I type:

> testing 123
>
> hello loader
>
> overflow test [press `.` until it halts]

I get the following **correct** output:

[image: test run]

At an earlier point in time I thought I would never need to learn a low level language. I was wrong. The blank comments are placeholders for once I learn more about what they do. I am primarily asking for feedback on the accuracy of the comments, then secondarily asking for efficiency of size and correctness of overall flow and layout.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Lots of review of the raw mechanics of your code.  Not much review of the *design*.  So here are just a few design tips.

## Use BPBs, because other people will.

```
start:          jmp        main             ; goto main
```

There are two reasons that Volume Boot Record programs do this.  The first and foremost is in order to skip over an embedded BIOS Parameter Block.  You may not think that you need a BPB in your volume.  You almost certainly will.  Others have thought that over the years, and later been bitten when they do things like not have a BPB and use tools from operating systems that *require* that various types of partition have a BPB in the VBR.  It bit IBM in the OS/2 Boot Manager.  It *will* bite you.

The second is that there are even tools (broken ones, that are fortunately not in wide use any more) that key off the first instruction in a VBR, expecting it to be a `jmp`.

## Will your code ever be run on an original 8088 manufactured in 1979?

> Note that the `cli` and the `sti` are **super important**.

But not for the reason stated.  They stop interrupts from occurring in the window where you have loaded only half of `ss:sp`, and the stack pointer is thus invalid.  This piece of 808x wisdom has been unnecessarily and erroneously extended to the other segment registers in that answer, even though there are no accompanying offsets being loaded with those other segments.  In truth, those other registers are not expected to have any particular values by interrupt handlers, and you don't need to temporarily disable interrupts in order to manipulate them.  8086 "far" memory model DOS programs manipulate `ds` and `es` all of the time without masking interrupts, just fine.

And the importance is overstated.  Since the 8088, a `mov ss` has implicitly caused interrupts (even some that `cli` *cannot mask*) to be deferred for one instruction, so that one can slip in a `mov sp` immediately after it and the two instructions will be implicitly interrupt-safe without an explicit `cli`/`sti` pair.  (Early 8088s had a bug, but the 8088 reference manual documented this as the behaviour.  It's still in the Intel reference manuals today.)  Since the 80386, we've had the `lss esp` instruction that loads the register pair in one instruction.

### Interesting historical perspective

In *PC Magazine* in 1987 Robert L. Hummel called the 8088 bug "a serious bug that should be attended to" and explained the (by then already folkloric) workaround of a `cli` and `sti` pairing.  In fact Intel had fixed the bug in 1981.  The 80386 had arrived in 1985.  *Thirty years later* people are still handing around folk rules for coding this stuff, which have even become distorted.

## Exit properly.

```
                  hlt                         ; halt the cpu
                welcome db "boot", 0x0A, 0x0D, 0x00
```

Congratulations!  You just executed a prompt string as code.

The IBM PC Compatible firmware provides two software interrupts for properly "exiting" a bootstrap program back to the firmware.  The *BIOS Boot Specification* explains their use.  Use them.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2006) [*The PC/AT boot process*](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/pcat-boot-process.html).  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2011). [*A PC/AT-style MBR bootstrap program for EFI partitioned discs*](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/Softwares/mbrcode-efi.html).  Softwares.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2006). [*All about BIOS parameter blocks*](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/bios-parameter-block.html).  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2006) [*The meaning and use of the OEM Name field in volume boot blocks*](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/volume-boot-block-oem-name-field.html).  Frequently Given Answers.
- Will Fastie (September/October 1983). "Tracing a Bug in the 8088". *PC Tech Notebook*  4.  p. 106
- Sergei Kiselev (2011) ["Stack change race condition"](http://www.malinov.com/Home/sergeys-projects/sergey-s-xt/historical-notes#TOC-Stack-change-race-condition).  *Historical Notes*.
- Robert L. Hummel (1987-12-08).  "PC Tutor: Defective 8088 chips". *PC Magazine*. Volume 6 Issue 21. ISSN 0888-8507.  Ziff-Davis. p.492.
- Compaq Computer Corporation; Phoenix Technologies Ltd; Intel Corporation. *BIOS Boot Specification*  1996-01-11.

Comment: Good advice except that the *BIOS Boot Specification* does not describe how to exit back to the firmware from a bootloader.  Instead, it describes what the *BIOS* does, not what the bootloader is required to do.  I'd also offer [this real bootloader source code](http://beroset.com/loader.html) as inspiration.

Comment: You haven't read it properly.  Read it slowly and in full, paying particular attention to Appendix D.

Comment: I'm actually quite familiar with it -- I was working at Compaq doing BIOS development when the document was written.  What it says is that if the OS is not present or is unable to load, it should execute `int 18h`.  Neither condition is true in this bootloader, so that advice is not applicable.

Answer (score 23):

You are very inconsistent with how you clear a register:

```
bgetkey:        mov        ax, 0            ; clear register a
```

and

```
main:           mov        ax, 0x0000       ; clear register a
```

I recommend `xor`ing the register with itself.

Example:

```
xor ax, ax
```

---

As recommended by [@icktoofay](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/28033/icktoofay), in this section:

```
bgetkey:        mov        ax, 0            ; clear register a
                mov        ah, 0x10         ; 
                int        16h              ; interrupt bios keyboard
                ret
```

Instead of clearing all of `ax` and changing `ax` separately, just do this:

```
mov ax, 0x1000
```

That way, you are changing the upper and lower bytes of `ax` in one instruction.

---

I find that it is common in bootloaders that I've seen to not use `org 0x7C00` as people find that it is taking the "easy way out".

Instead, people often manuall setup the segments like this:

```
cli
mov ax,07C0h
mov ds,ax
mov gs,ax
mov fs,ax
mov es,ax
```

and then this to set up the stack(see the [bios memory mapping](http://wiki.osdev.org/Memory_Map_(x86)) where where the stack is located):

```
mov ax,07E0h
mov ss,ax
mov bp,ax

mov sp,0xff
sti
```

Note that the `cli` and the `sti` are **super important**. When messing around with segments, interrupts might "accidentally" fire, which could mess up your program. `cli` will disable interrupts and `sti` will re-enable interrupts.

---

On some lines like this:

```
mov        byte [bx], al    ; copy keystroke to memory
```

I do not think that the `byte` is necessary since `al` is already a byte in size, although I have not tested that theory.

---

Ascii numbers like `0x0A` and `0x0D` can be a little confusing, because some people don't know what they are, and others it can take a second to process.

To improve readability, I recommend that you use `%define` to define a macro for these numbers, like in C.

For example,

```
%define NEWLINE 0x0A
```

---

In your `prints` routine, each iteration you are restoring `ah` with `0x0e`, even though `ah` isn't touched at all during the routine.

I recommend putting

```
mov ah, 0x0e
```

*before* the `.loop` label, so you are unnecessarily updating `ah`.

---

I recommend you check out [this post](http://forum.nasm.us/index.php?topic=1791.0) for a good example of a bootloader.

---

I will continue to look through the code and add more improvements that I see necessary.

Comment: Re. the recommendation to replace `mov ax, 0` with `mov al, 0`: that’s true, but I’d go even further and say that if you’re changing both the high and the low byte, change them both at once with a `mov ax, 0x1000`.

Comment: @icktoofay Ah yes! That is a great idea. Do you mind if I modify my post to accomodate to your recommendation?

Comment: By all means, please do!

Comment: The only need I see for disabling interrupts in that code is that MOV can't update both SS and SP atomically. An interrupt coming between the two updates would use an inconsistent stack pointer. Updating the other segment registers can safely be done without disabling interrupts.

Comment: -1 This answer is (mostly) bunk. The BIOS sets your initial segments for you (org 0x7c00 simply tells your compiler to assume that is starting address). It generates no code, so is not a "cheat". Trust that it does the right thing, unless you're on a 8086 from the late 70s. xor ax, ax and mov ax, 0 are semantically the same, except one is slightly faster, but not enough to care, because it's not in a loop. Moving to SS temporarily prevents interrupts, as pointed out elsewhere, and doesn't matter anyways, since you can lss esp, unless you plan on running on *very* old hardware.

Comment: @phyrfox Thank you very much for the feedback; you brought up some valid points. However, I don't know what to think about your point, "The BIOS sets your intial segments for you," because in Edward's answer, he wrote, "The BIOS calling your loader should have CS and DS both set to 0 but it's unfortunately not guaranteed. Some old BIOS would call 7C0:0 rather than 0:7C00 so most boot loader code explictly sets the segment registers."

Comment: @SirPython I'd actually forgotten it was 0000:7C00... it's been ages. However, my main point is that CS will be 0000, not 07C0, on any hardware the OP cares to use, including VMs. It hasn't been broken since the early 8086's, so there's really no point in carrying on with that code anymore. It's a leftover "folklore" that people keep dredging up long after its expiration date. If you're going to relocate your loader, then you need to eventually far jump, but not because your registers are incorrect.

Comment: @phyrfox : There were many BIOSes in late 80 and early 90s that transferred control to 0x07c0:0x0000. In particular the el Torito spec for CD-ROM boots specifically documented 0x07c0:0x0000 (not 0x0000:0x7c00). Some BIOS developers took it literally. As for VMs not using something other than 0x0000:0x7c00 that is incorrect. BOCH (2.6.8 at least) follows El Torito when booting from CD-ROM and uses 0x07c0:0x0000 and if you boot from floppy or hard drive it uses 0x0000:0x7c00. To believe it doesn't matter isn't helpful. It does , and you can easily code a bootloader to do right thing in any case

Answer (score 19):

I see a number of things that may help you improve your code.

### Eliminate "magic numbers"

This code has a number of "magic numbers," that is, unnamed constants such as 2, 0x0e, 0x10, etc.  Generally it's better to avoid that and give such constants meaningful names.  That way, if anything ever needs to be changed, you won't have to go hunting through the code for all instances of "7" and then trying to determine if this *particular* 0x07 is relevant to the desired change or if it is some other constant that happens to have the same value. With NASM, you can use the `%define` directive:

```
%define KBDINT 16h
```

Then in the code:

```
int KBDINT
```

### Use `XOR` to clear a register

The idiomatic way to clear a register in x86 assembly language is to use `xor`:

```
xor ax,ax       ; ax = 0
```

This instruction coding is shorter than `mov ax,0000h`.

### Use comments to indicate register usage

Keeping track of register usage is one of the most important tasks for an assembly language programmer.  A useful technique for tracking this is the use of comments.  For example, instead of this:

```
bgetkey:        mov        ax, 0            ; clear register a
                mov        ah, 0x10         ; 
                int        KBDINT           ; interrupt bios keyboard
                ret                         ; return
```

write this:

```
;****************************************************************************
;
; bgetkey - use BIOS call to get a keystroke; blocks until key available
;
; INPUT:        none
; OUTPUT:       ah = BIOS scan code, al = ASCII char
; DESTROYED:    none
;****************************************************************************
bgetkey:       
     mov        ah, 0x10         ; 
     int        KBDINT           ; interrupt bios keyboard
     ret                         ; return
```

### Use macros to simplify code

Although the macro support in NASM is not very good, it does exist and can be used to simplify your code.  For instance, the routine above is only accessed once.  The shortened version above is only three instructions but would be only two instructions and eliminate a `call` if it were placed inline in the code.  I'd write it like this:

```
%macro BIOSWAITKEY 0
        mov        ah, 0x10         ; 
        int        KBDINT           ; interrupt bios keyboard
%endmacro
```

Then it's used in the code like this:

```
type:   
        mov        si, qbuf         ; set byte buffer ptr for printing
        BIOSWAITKEY
        mov        [qbuf], al       ; copy key byte to buffer
```

### Set the segment registers explicitly

The BIOS calling your loader *should* have `CS` and `DS` both set to `0` but it's unfortunately not guaranteed.  Some old BIOS would call `7C0:0` rather than `0:7C00` so most boot loader code explictly sets the segment registers.  Your code sets the `DS` register only and not `SS`.  For a robust bootloader, set the segment registers explictly to either `0` or to equal whatever `CS` happens to be.

### Carefully consider stack usage

The `prints` routine currently pushes and then pops all registers.  This routine is not speed critical, but it's useful to get into the habit of thinking carefully about stack usage.  In this case, I would probably only save `AX` and `BX` instead or maybe just `BX`.  The code does not really need to preserve the value of `SI` and probably not `AX` either, with some small changes to the calling code.

### Put each label on its own line

Maintaining code which has code on the same line as labels is a pain.  Better practice is to have each label be on a line by itself.  This makes it much easier to maintain the code.

### Avoid branching where practical

Branching is a costly operation to the processor, so avoiding branching (that is conditional or unconditional jumps) saves cycles and time.  In this code, we have this:

```
prints:         push       ax               ; modified per previous point
                push       bx               ;
.loop:          mov        ah, 0x0e         ; 
                mov        al, [si]         ; 
                cmp        al, 0            ; check for null terminator
                jz         print_end        ; stop printing
                mov        bh, 0x00         ; 
                mov        bl, 0x07         ; 
                int        0x10             ; interrupt bios tty
                inc        si               ; next character
                jmp        .loop            ; jump beginning
print_end:      pop        bx               ; 
                pop        ax               ;
                ret                         ; return
```

This means that the the unconditional `jmp` at the end of the loop is always executed.  Instead, it would be better to restructure the code to only have a single conditional branch within the loop.

```
prints:         
        push       ax               ; 
        push       bx               ;
        jmp        .begin           ; skip over loop first iteration
.loop:          
        mov        bx, PAGE0WHTBLK  ; page 0, white on black
        mov        ah, TTYOUT       ; 
        int        VIDINT           ; interrupt bios tty
        inc        si               ; next character
.begin:
        mov        al, [si]         ; 
        cmp        al, 0            ; check for null terminator
        jnz        .loop            ; keep printing
        pop        bx               ; 
        pop        ax               ;
        ret                         ; return
```

### Set the `AX` register close to the `INT` instruction

To make it easier for another programmer to understand your code, it's a good idea to set the `AX` (or `AH` register) just before the `INT` instruction the calls a BIOS or operating system function.  That way the two most important pieces of information, namely "which interrupt" and "which service" are near each other, making it easy to look them up.  Better still, use named constants as well as putting them near each other.

### Eliminate unused variables

The `.buf` area in `bgetkey` is never used and should be eliminated.

### Prefer assemble-time to runtime mathematics

The `newinput` label starts with these three lines:

```
    mov        bx, mem          ; set register b to memory start
    add        bx, word 2       ; increment by size of memory ptr
    mov        word [mem], bx   ; set pointer at first memory byte
```

Better would be to let the assembler do the calculation instead:

```
    mov        bx, mem+2        ; point to available space
    mov        word [mem], bx   ; save pointer to available space
```

Better still would be to eliminate the use of `mem` to store the pointer.  That is, just use `bx` to store the pointer and use all of `mem` as the buffer area.

### Simplify calling mechanisms where appropriate

The `qbuf` structure appears to be set up solely for the purpose of printing single character output.  In the code, the first byte of `qbuf` is set to a value and then `si` pointed to `qbuf` and then the `prints` routine is called.  Better would be to simplify by creating a routine to simply and directly print a single character.  In fact, this is what the BIOS video TTY output routine (that you're already using) actually does already, so make a function for that:

```
;****************************************************************************
;
; printch: prints a single character to screen
;
; INPUT:        al = character to print
; OUTPUT:       none
; DESTROYED:    none
;****************************************************************************
printch:
            push       ax               ; 
            push       bx               ;
            mov        bx, PAGE0WHTBLK  ; page 0, white on black
            mov        ah, TTYOUT       ; 
            int        VIDINT           ; interrupt bios tty
            pop        bx               ; 
            pop        ax               ;
            ret                         ; return
```

Again, a macro is now useful for using this routine:

```
%macro PRINTCHAR 1
    %ifnidni %1,al
        mov al, %1
    %endif
        call printch
%endmacro
```

Now it can be used like any of these:

```
PRINTCHAR al
PRINTCHAR [bx]
PRINTCHAR CR
```

### Name important memory locations

One very important but unnamed memory location is the end of the `mem` area.  I would modify the existing code to look instead like this:

```
        mem        db 0
times 0200h - 3 - ($ - $$)db 0
        endofmem   db 0
        stop       dw 0xAA55
```

### Take advantage of every byte

Especially in a bootloader, where every byte matters, it's useful to take advantage of every available byte.  For instance, after your code begins, the "welcome" messsage is no longer needed.  You could overlay that message within the `mem` buffer to allow it to be overwritten by input from the user.  Similarly, technically, once the sector has been read into memory, the signature `0xAA55` bytes could be overwritten as well.  Similarly, the error message strings can also be combined to save a few bytes.

### Consider reformatting the code

You may, of course, do it any way that pleases you, but typical x86 assembly language code is formatted with labels in column 1 and code indented to column 9 (that is, the size of one traditional tab stop).  After that, comments are most often aligned (as you have done) at some multiple of tab stops.

### Carefully consider register allocation

By using another register, such as `di` rather than `bx` to point to the memory buffer, we can avoid having to save the `bx` register.

### Comments should tell why, not what

Comments should generally explain why you're doing what you do, and not simply repeat what the instruction does.  So this is not a good comment:

```
hlt                         ; halt the cpu
```

This, however, is a better comment:

```
je         readmemdone      ; if found begin another input line
```

### Putting it all together

Applying all of these suggestions yields a program that is easier to maintain, easier to read, smaller and better structured:

### boot.asm

```
    bits       16                       ; 16 bit real mode
    org        0x7C00                   ; loader start in memory

%define KBDINT 16h
%define VIDINT 10h
%define TTYOUT 0eh
%define PAGE0WHTBLK 0x0007
%define CR 0x0D
%define LF 0x0A
%define NUL 0x00

%macro BIOSWAITKEY 0
        mov        ah, 0x10             ; 
        int        KBDINT               ; interrupt bios keyboard
%endmacro

%macro PRINTSTR 1
    mov si, %1
    call prints
%endmacro

%macro PRINTCHAR 1
    %ifnidni %1,al
        mov al, %1
    %endif
        call printch
%endmacro

start:  jmp        main                 ; goto main

;****************************************************************************
;
; prints: prints a NUL-terminated string to screen
;
; INPUT:        ds:si ==> NUL-terminated buffer to print
; OUTPUT:       none
; DESTROYED:    bx, si
;****************************************************************************
prints:         
        jmp        .begin               ;
.loop:          
        call       printch              ; print the char in AL
        inc        si                   ; next character
.begin:
        mov        al, [si]             ; 
        cmp        al, NUL              ; check for NUL terminator
        jnz        .loop                ; keep printing
        ret                             ; return

;****************************************************************************
;
; printch: prints a single character to screen
;
; INPUT:        al = character to print
; OUTPUT:       none
; DESTROYED:    bx
;****************************************************************************
printch:
        push       ax                   ; 
        mov        bx, PAGE0WHTBLK      ; page 0, white on black
        mov        ah, TTYOUT           ; 
        int        VIDINT               ; interrupt bios tty
        pop        ax                   ;
        ret                             ; 

main:   
        xor        ax, ax               ; 
        mov        ds, ax               ; 
        mov        es, ax               ; both es and ds are now 0
        PRINTSTR   welcome              ; print welcome string
newinput:       
        mov        di, inputbuffer      ; point to memory buffer
type:           
        BIOSWAITKEY                     ; fetch a key
        PRINTCHAR  al                   ; echo to screen
        mov        ah, NUL              ; make sure string is always terminated
        cmp        di, endofmem         ; check for overflow 
        je         oom                  ; halt  if Out Of Memory (oom)
        mov        [di], ax             ; copy keystroke + NUL to memory
        inc        di                   ; advance to next byte in buffer
        cmp        al, CR               ; CR signals end of input
        jne        type                 ; goto next key if not found
        PRINTSTR   newline              ; print newline
        PRINTSTR   inputbuffer          ; print string from memory
        PRINTSTR   newline              ; another newline
        jmp        newinput             ; keep getting lines forever

oom:           
        PRINTSTR   outomem              ; print out of memory message
here:
        jmp here                        ; sit and spin

        outomem db CR, LF, "out of memory", CR  ; terminated by newline below
                db LF, "halting", CR
        newline db LF, NUL
        inputbuffer        db NUL
        ; welcome will be overwritten by input
        welcome db "Welcome to the loaderless bootloader.", CR, LF, 
                db "Type anything and it will be repeated by the magic of "
                db "assembly language!", CR, LF, NUL        

times 0200h - 2 - ($ - $$) db NUL
        endofmem   dw 0xAA55
```

### Use real version control rather than just file copies

While it's important to have backup files when you're changing source rapidly and experimentally, you might consider using a more appropriate mechanism for that.  I'd suggest that you might want to use [`git`](https://git-scm.com/) instead of creating multiple gzip files.  That way it will be easier to document why changes were made, even if you don't plan on sharing the code.

Answer (score 18):

I echo most of [SirPython’s recommendations](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/94231) (excepting possibly a detail about the recommended segment-setup code—I prefer setting up a flat memory space with all segment registers zero), but there’s a few other things I might change as well. I should note that a few of these may be more a matter of taste.

### Hexadecimal constants

You are inconsistent with notation for hexadecimal constants. You use the `0xABCD` syntax in some places, and the `0ABCDh` syntax in others. I prefer the `0ABCDh` syntax, but that’s just me.

### (Essentially) using `.data` where `.bss` would suffice

You’re putting your line buffer into the space allotted for your bootloader. As you write your code, the amount of space available will dwindle. If you need some space initialized to some particular initial values, sure, it’s rather convenient, so you ought to keep it there, but if you don’t need it initialized to anything in particular, you don’t need to cram it into those 512 bytes; you’ve got nearly the entire address space at your disposal. (Starting at `500h` up ’till you hit your bootloader code itself, and then up until… gee, something else. But you’ve got a lot of space.) Keep in mind, though, that if you want it to be zero-initialized, now you have to zero-initialize it yourself.

### String instructions

I see lots of code accessing a buffer, doing something with it, and then incrementing that pointer. Do yourself a favor and read up on the string instructions made available to you by the x86 architecture: in particular, `lodsb` and `stosb` may become some of your best friends.

### `inc`

`add reg, 1` is almost never necessary. Save some space and use `inc reg`. (With `add`, you need space to store the `1`. Not so for `inc`.) There’s also `dec` to decrement, should you need it later.

### Testing equality to zero

Along the same lines, consider using `test reg, reg` rather than `cmp reg, 0`. Again, this avoids the need to store an immediate `0`. (This is also why `xor reg, reg` is better than `mov reg, 0` when `reg` is bigger than a byte.)

### Indentation

Here, a matter of style. When I use the local dot-labels, I usually indent them to indicate some sort of structure, e.g.:

```
read_line:
  .next_character:
  .done:
```

Also, the named `db`/`dw` definitions *are* introducing a label, so I would flush those left as I would for any other label.

### Operand size hints

This was mentioned by SirPython, but I assert more strongly that you can absolutely remove the operand size hint on, e.g., `mov byte [bx], al`. There are some places you can’t remove them (most commonly when using an instruction with a memory operand and an immediate operand), but I see it as clutter when it’s inferrable otherwise.

### Choice of assembler

This is entirely personal preference, but I used NASM for a while, until I came across what I believe is a very odd bug where it started having off-by-one errors in jump targets across 16- and 32-bit boundaries. When I hit that, I switched to [FASM](http://flatassembler.net/) (which has a very similar syntax). That fixed my problem, and I’ve since grown to like it simply for the few syntactic differences it does make<sup>1</sup>. You may want to try it too.

---

<sup>1</sup> One concrete thing FASM does that NASM doesn’t is it will remember what type you declared a data definition to be. So, for example:

```
some_variable db 0

some_function:
        mov     [some_variable], 123
        ret
```

…will work; the `mov` will be a byte-`mov` because `some_variable` was defined as a byte. (Of course, this can be overridden with an explicit operand size specified.) FASM’s style of macro I also think looks a bit nicer than NASM’s, and FASM’s `virtual` is quite nice for laying out memory (like your line buffer) outside your program.

Comment: It's good to know `lodsb` and `stosb` (and `scasb`) and friends, but it's also worth knowing that they aren't necessarily faster than the corresponding equivalent instructions.  Testing in context is the best way to know.

Comment: @Edward: I was recommending them not for speed, but for code size, as space is at a premium inside a bootloader. Plus they’re rather convenient.

Answer (score 11):

Everything from SyrPython and icktoofay, plus ...

Four instructions:

```
mov        ah, 0x0e         ; 
mov        al, [si]         ; 
cmp        al, 0            ; check for null terminator
jz         print_end        ; stop printing
```

I would suggest:

```
mov        ax,0x0e00        ; clears al
or         al,[si]          ; sets Z accordingly (if [si] is 0)
jz         print_end        ; stop printing
```

---

If I understand correctly (I used another assembler back in the days. Borland I think)

```
newinput:       mov        bx, mem          ; set register b to memory start
                add        bx, word 2       ; increment by size of memory ptr
```

You move the offset of mem in bx.  Then why not do

```
newinput:       mov bx, mem + 2
```

Like you do elsewhere ?

---

It seems you never use DX nor DI (and you still will not if you use the well suggested lodsb, that you may or may not use with rep, depending on your future direction)

You have 8 registers Ax Cx Dx Bx SP BP SI DI
SP, you will mostly not play with
SI and DI are usually used for offsets (what you use BX for)
AX is your main register
CX is mostly used for counting (and shifts)
DX is for other data
BP is mostly used for stack frame, which you don't care about so, another free one.

---

For using xor reg,reg, this is indeed a preferred way, with the only downside that it affects the flags so you cannot very well use it while pipelining your code (putting the operations in such order they are executed in parallel)

ie:

```
cmp bx, 2 <- U
mov ax, 1 <- V
je  label
```

cmp will be executed in pipeline U, and the mov in pipeline V because it does not affect the cmp operation.

But this may be a bit over the top for a loader.

Comment: The U/V bit I'd agree is over the top in this case, but the info would surely be decent when they get around to, for example, trying to optimize the video hardware stuff.